# Function composition exam question

Tags: functions

is this correct

[image]

For the first one in i (4)

g(g(2*4)+2)=g((2*4)+2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g(g(4))=g(2\cdot 4+2)=g(10)=2\cdot 10+2=22$$

Comment: Thanks. So, would the next one be f(g(9/3))=g(3)=f(2*3)+2 = 11?

Comment: And then the following one would not be valid?  since R > B - R>R  the second one being B and the first one on the being R , they need to be equal ?

Comment: Also for the final one, how do you check multiple functions at once, unsure of the order i'd go in

Answer (score 2):

No, you haven't finished: $$g\circ g = g((2\cdot x + 2)) \overset{ x = 4}{=}g(\underbrace{2\cdot 4 + 2}_{g(4)}) = g(10) = 2\cdot 10 + 2 = 22$$

Comment: Don't really know what i'm supposed to follow up on tbh

Comment: Can you see now? You need to evaluate $g(4) = a$, then use that value evaluate $g(g(4)) = g(a)$

Comment: @user113523  It surely was not my intent to *harrass* you and I'm sorry you feel that way. I alert users who haven't accepted answers precisely because regular users who help out do so voluntarily, and many of them get offended when there's no appreciation expressed in words or in accepted answers, and as a result, may downvote, or just decide to stop answering the user's questions. I just don't want that to happen, since many users aren't aware of the site's etiquette. And so, I try to alert users about that.